# MergeSort without second recursion call in C

Tags: c, recursion, mergesort

I've to remove the second call recursion of *MergeSort*, (`MergeSort(tabla, m + 1, iu);`)

I've tried really hard, but no matter what I do, it always sorts the table in parts, but it never ends completely sorted.

```
int MergeSort(int* tabla, int ip, int iu) {
    int m, A;
    if (ip > iu)return ERR;
    if (ip == iu)return 0;

    m = (ip + iu) / 2;

    A = MergeSort(tabla, ip, m);
    A += MergeSort(tabla, m + 1, iu);
    return Merge(tabla, ip, iu, m) + A;
}
```

P.S: `Merge` merges the table.

```
int Merge(int * tabla, int ip, int iu, int imedio) {
    int i = ip, j = imedio + 1, k = 0, OB = 0;
    int *taux = (int*) calloc(iu - ip + 1, sizeof (int));
    if (!taux)return ERR;

    while (i <= imedio && j <= iu) {
        OB++;
        if (tabla[i] < tabla[j]) {
            taux[k] = tabla[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            taux[k] = tabla[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    if (i > imedio) { /* copy the right table */
        while (j <= iu) {
            taux[k] = tabla[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    } else if (j > iu) { /* copy the left table */
        while (i <= imedio) {
            taux[k] = tabla[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
    }

    for (i = ip; i <= iu; i++) /* Copy function */
        tabla[i] = taux[i - ip];

    free(taux);

    return OB;
}
```

[EDIT]: Add the Merge code.

Comment: This is a charming story that lacks a question. You wrote this program, it doesn't work. What's the question?

Comment: This actually is not tail recursion. *Tail* recursion mans that the last call is a recursive call. That's not what this code does.

Comment: Furthermore, what is the implementation of `Merge` since we do not know, it is hard to debug the entire program.

Comment: If your question is "how do I debug a ten line program that I wrote that doesn't work?" there's some good advice here: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I don't quite get your point... Are you saying 'the program doesn't sort the array properly as it is now', or 'the program stops sorting properly when I break it by removing some part of it'...?

Comment: As CommuSoft said, there's no tail recursion in your program, so ....what do you want to remove?

Comment: @CiaPan: As far as I can tell the OP is saying "I took one of the wings off my airplane and now it doesn't fly".  That's not a question, and really not a very surprising result either. I think this should be closed.

Comment: You split the array in halves (range `ip..iu` into two ranges `ip..m` and `m+1..iu`), sort them and then merge. For the merge to make sense **both parts** must be **sorted** prior to merging. How would you make the second half sorted if you remove the second recursive call...?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove tail recursion because there is no tail recursion in your algorithm.  Even the final call to `Merge` cannot be converted to a tail call because you add its result to a local value. Conversely, the compile may inline the code of the `Merge` function if it is `static` and defined before the `MergeSort` function, or you can pass the initial count as an argument

There might be a problem in the way you split the array: `m` is the mid point, the left half should go from `ip` included to `m` excluded, while the right half would go from `m` included to `iu` excluded.  This would be consistent with an invocation at the top level as:

```
n = MergeSort(array, 0, count);
```

In your code, you handle the upper boundary as included and pass `m+1` as the starting index for the right half, but it leads to more complicated code and counter-intuitive invocation at the top level.

You also need to test for allocation error at every point during recursion.

Here is a simplified version of `Merge`:

```
static int Merge(int *tabla, int ip, int iu, int imedio, int count) {
    int i = ip, j = imedio, k = 0;
    int *taux = malloc((iu - ip) * sizeof(*taux));
    if (!taux) return ERR;

    while (i < imedio && j < iu) {
        count++;
        if (tabla[i] < tabla[j]) {
            taux[k++] = tabla[i++];
        } else {
            taux[k++] = tabla[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i < imedio) { /* copy the remaining elements from left table */
        taux[k++] = tabla[i++];
    }
    while (j < iu) { /* copy the remaining elements from right table */
        taux[k++] = tabla[j++];
    }
    for (i = ip; i < iu; i++) { /* copy back to source */
        tabla[i] = taux[i - ip];
    }
    free(taux);

    return count;
}
```

If you **really** want to remove the second call to `MergeSort`, you can use a loop:

```
int MergeSort(int* tabla, int ip, int iu) {
    int m, count = 0, n, a, b;

    if (ip > iu) return ERR;

    m = (ip + iu) / 2;
    if (m == ip)
        return 0;

    for (a = ip, b = m; a < iu; a = b, b = iu) {
        n = MergeSort(tabla, a, b);
        if (n == ERR) return ERR;
        count += n;
    }
    return Merge(tabla, ip, iu, m, count);
}
```

Note that you can improve efficiency with these ideas:

- A single auxiliary array could be allocated at the top level and passed as an argument to a `MergeSortAux` internal function, for much improved efficiency.
- Copying the remaining elements from the right part is not needed.
- The auxiliary array does not need to be as large as the source array.
- There are a few extra tricks to decrease the number of comparisons if the array is already sorted in ascending or descending order.

Comment: Does this answer help?  Who is asking you to remove tail recursion?